# Weird jQuery.load behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, onload

I am trying to load an external html into the div using jQuery.load() method.
I call this method from document.ready().

**html.1**

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/script1.js'></script>
...
```

**script1.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.dropzone').load('drawings.html');
});
```

***The file is loaded, but is not shown till I press F5*** (refresh), and sometimes even ctrl F5, some times (3-5). If I will not press F5 , the page will be never shown, however with some F5 presses the page is always shown.

The HTML that is loaded into div does lots of canvas drawing in its window.onload.

**drawings.html**

```
<script>
var init = function() {
   var container = document.getElementById('MyCanvas');
   var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   canvas.width = container.clientWidth;
   canvas.height = 1000;
   container.appendChild(canvas);
   return canvas;
}

window.onload = function()
{
   var canvas = init();
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   context.beginPath();
   //... lots of drawings here
   context.closePath();
};

</script>
...
<div id='MyCanvas'>
</div>
```

When I remove this canvas thing and place some static HTML instead, it is shown without any problem.

Can somebody shed a light on what is going on here?

Comment: Well you can add an window.location(); after the div dropzone load

Comment: @JonathanRomer: What for? I trying to load it into div.

Comment: i ment try location.reload(); acts like an 'f5'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing window.onload to a named function, and call that function in the callback to load. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div.dropzone').load('drawings.html', function() {
      doMyNewNamedFunction();
    }
});
```

Comment: He may not ever know the named function as it exists in an external script... which he may or may not have control over.

Comment: Well, you can manually trigger window.onload() again in the callback, but I'm not sure what side effects that may cause.

Comment: Assuming that I know this named function in advance, this works just fine. So I accept your answer, and +1 it. Now the question is, how to find this function name. Is there any way just to "scan" html file and to find all functions that are there? But I guess  this is another SO question.

Comment: It is possible! Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589186/possible-to-extract-functions-from-a-javascript-file

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
$.get('/drawings.html', function(data) {
  $('div.dropzone').html(data);
  console.log('Load was performed.');
});
```

Comment: This use of `.load` is not deprecated, it's the event one that is depreciated.

Comment: Also, its the code in drawings.html that is the problem: it assumes that window.load has not fired... which is only the case sometimes... simply by chance.

Comment: @BrianNoah: Tried it: didn't make any difference.

Comment: @Flot2011, make sure to check out your console to see where the error is. also try console.log(data) to see it you're getting an error or not.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a race condition, sometimes the window load event fires before your div is done loading in content, resulting in the loaded in js binding to an event that has already been triggered and won't be triggered again.

Comment: I agree, it definitely seems so, The question is what can I do?

Comment: You could not use the window load event, and instead use the callback of the .load method as suggested by that steve guy.

Answer (score 0):

window.onload may have already fired by the time drawings.html is loaded.  Why not use jquery and the document's ready event to do all of your init()ialization and drawing.  jQuery will always call your function, even if the event has already passed.

btw - I am a huge proponent of real javascript... but this is a case where you already have a solid framework on the page... use it ;)